# How to access the database when XAP is located on Azure Blob storage?

Tags: sql-server, silverlight, azure, wcf-ria-services, azure-blob-storage

I have stored my XAP files to Azure blob storage.

The Silverlight website in Azure is not able to access the database by RIA Services. The error message is 'The remote server returned an error: NotFound'.. When the XAP file is stored in the VM locally the application works properly.

Any idea why that is the case?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

There are two problems, first the Service was pointed to as a relative source. This can't be the case when putting the XAP on blob storage, as the service doesn't live on the blob and needs to be specified.  For example when using EF4/RIA

```
Context = new CBDomainContext(new Uri("http://login.MySite.com/ClientBin/SC-DataServices-Web-Services-CBDomainService.svc", UriKind.Absolute));
```

After that there is a need to solve the cross-domain situation by adding clientaccesspolicy.xml to the Web-project.   Simply follow this instructions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx